# How to persist an Entity that only contains a collection and an ID?

Tags: database, postgresql, jpa, persistence, openjpa

I have a problem where I cannot persist or merge an object that only contains an ID and a collection of other objects. If I add another field it will commit the transaction as normal. Also, if I change the ID generation strategy to AUTO it will work as well.

The rest of my team uses "IDENTITY" instead of "AUTO", so I want to be consistent with them. Their entities are all more than just an ID + Collection, so it works fine for them. The following is what I want to make work:

```
@Entity
public class Filter implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } )
   private ArrayList<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

   public Filter() {

   }

}
```

**ErrorMessage:**

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 25 {prepstmnt 693640431 INSERT INTO Filter () VALUES ()} [code=0, state=42601]
FailedObject: middle.ware.Filter@630cd05
```

Essentially, since it's just an ID and a Join Table, it dies when trying to persist or merge the Filter without any fields.

**Workarounds**

- Change GenerationType.IDENTITY to GenerationType.AUTO.

  -The only con seems to be that the initial starting primary keys to jump around by 50, then it begins incrementing by 1.
- Change GenerationType to TABLE

  -This seems to be what AUTO picked.
- Add an arbitrary field to the entity (i.e., String test =
  "test").

  -Simply making the entity have one more field makes it persist. However, I do not need this field there; I just want a collection
- Make the relationships bidirectional.

  -By making the relationships bidirectional, the tables have an id going back (instead of just being an id). This only works because Filter is owned by another record.

Comment: If your JPA provider doesn't support having INSERT statements with no columns then raise a BUG on it. I do that with the provider I use (DataNucleus) and it generates the correct SQL.

Comment: Using AUTO isn't really an answer since AUTO means leave it to the provider what strategy to use, and they may just use IDENTITY under the covers which ends up with the same problem.

Comment: Removed from author

Comment: Right now I'm on PostgreSQL, and doing insert statements without columns via straight SQL brings up the same error. However, if I do it like so: "INSERT INTO Filter(id) VALUES(10)", it'll do a no kidding insert. Are you saying that I should be able to just call "INSERT INTO Filter() VALUES()" without any problems from SQL statements alone, and that it should know to insert an ID by itself?

Comment: The JPA provider I use does something like "INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (DEFAULT)" for Postgresql when it realises there are no columns to provide, which is in the PostgreSQL manual as what should be used. So OpenJPA clearly doesn't bother doing that check ...

Comment: Can you post your code, how you are trying to save the data?

Comment: @SreenathReddy how he tries to persist the code isn't really relevant ... the Entity has no columns other than the "id" column and that is attributed in the INSERT statement, hence no columns present in the INSERT.

Comment: @Neil thanks for the feedback. I'll have another look at it once I get to work on Monday and try switching out my jpa provider. I've also read around that persisting only IDs for the sake of maintaining a relationship to a collection of objects (as I'm doing in my question above) doesn't make sense and that I should rethink my entity. If that's so, can someone point me in the direction of an article/book where I can read the correct way to structure this type of entity?

Comment: @NeilStockton I agree with you. I just want to see how he is doing that to cross chcck if he is missing something while saving the data.

Comment: Could you show a table sctructure? In psql `\d+ Filter`

Comment: Table "public.filter"
 Column |  Type  | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id     | bigint | not null  | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "filter_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

Comment: From there I have a join table filter_rule, and a rule table.

Comment: I've tried both Eclipselink 2.6.3 and OpenJPA 2.4.1 and they both work in the same manner in regards to the collections and workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would make the code bidirectional, as you have already pointed out, and make use of the "@PrePersist" annotation, to set the id to the "Rules" objects. Something like:

Rule.java

```
@Entity
public class Rule implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Filter filter;

    // getters, setters, equals, hashcode, toString...
}
```

Filter.java

```
@Entity
public class Filter implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy="filter" )
    private List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if (rules != null) {
            rules.forEach(item -> item.setFilter(this));
        }
    }

    // getters, setters, equals, hashcode, toString...
}
```

FilterRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<Filter, Integer> { }
```

AnUnitTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AnUnitTest {
    @Autowired
    private FilterRepository filterRepository;

    @After
    public void clearDatabase() {
        bodyPartRespository.deleteAll();

        filterRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFilterRules() {
        Rule aRule = Rule.builder()
                .description("A")
                .build();
        Rule anotherRule = Rule.builder()
                .description("B")
                .build();

        Filter filter = Filter.builder()
                .rules(Arrays.asList(aRule, anotherRule))
                .build();

        filterRepository.saveAndFlush(filter);

        List<Filter> all = filterRepository.findAll();

        all.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The code above runs fine for me.

I hope this solve your issue.

Cheers, Nikolas.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your problematic with 4 different examples :

1. Just the ID

   > @Entity
   >   public class Case1 implements Serializable {
   >
   > private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   >
   > @Id
   >   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   >   private Long id;
   >
   > // ...
   >   }
2. The ID + 1 String column

   > @Entity
   >   public class Case2 implements Serializable {
   >
   > private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   >
   > @Id
   >   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   >   private Long id;
   >   private String name;
   >
   > // ...
   >   }
3. The ID + 1 OneToMany association

> a. with cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }

```
> @Entity
> public class Case3 implements Serializable {
>         
> private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>            
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
> private Long id;
> @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } )
> private ArrayList<AdminUtilisateur> users = new ArrayList<>();        
>  // ...
>}
```

> b. without cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }

```
> @Entity
> public class Case4 implements Serializable {
>         
> private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>            
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
> private Long id;
>  
> @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
> private ArrayList<AdminUtilisateur> users = new ArrayList<>();      
>  // ...
>}
```

The results was fine with SQL queries (tested under PostgreSQL 9.3).
But with javax.persistence, i've got a different results :

> 1. Case 1 : Exception Description: The list of fields to insert into the table [DatabaseTable(case1)] is empty.  You must define at least
>      one mapping for this table.
> 2. Case 2 : Works fine.
> 3. Case 3 : Local Exception Stack:  Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652):
>      org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>      Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la valeur d'une
>      clé dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « rule_code_key »
> 4. Case 4 : Exception Description: The list of fields to insert into the table [DatabaseTable(case4)] is empty.  You must define at least
>      one mapping for this table.

The explication of the errors on cases 1, 3 & 4 is simple.

1. For Case 3, when you have **cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }** the orm try to persist **Rule** before persisting **Filter** and everything depends on the need, for my case **Rule** it already exists.
2. For Case 1 & 4, you're trying to persist just the id of **Filter** on table N° 1 and the id of rule + the id of Filter on a **Join Table**. 
   Which means that the Filter has just the ID *Synonymous of a design problem* = You must define at least one mapping for this table.